# OpenCV Checkerboard Generation - Recieving an Error

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I am attempting to write a function which takes a width, a height, and CvType and makes a checkerboard pattern from it. My current implementation is giving me the error Invalid Paramter Passed to C runtime function.

```
Mat MainWindow::makeCheckMat(int width, int height, int type){

int checkSize = 8;
Mat checkMat(width, height, type);

uchar color=0;
for(int i = 0 ; i < width ; i += checkSize ){
    color=~color;
    for(int j = 0 ; j < height ; j += checkSize ){

        Point topLeft(i, j);
        int bottomRightX = i + checkSize;
        int bottomRightY = j + checkSize;

        if ( bottomRightX >= width ){
            bottomRightX = width - 1;
        }
        if ( bottomRightY >= height ){
            bottomRightY = height - 1;
        }
        Point bottomRight(bottomRightX, bottomRightY);

        //THE CODE BREAKS HERE

        Mat ROI = checkMat( Rect(topLeft, bottomRight) );
        ROI.setTo(Scalar::all(color));

        color=~color;
    }
}

return checkMat;
```

Here is a log of all values printed in //THE CODE BREAKS HERE location, right before the code breaks...

```
width:   799
height:  801
i:  0
j:  792
bottomRightX:  8
bottomRightY:  800
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
```

Comment: You wrote `Mat checkMat(width, height, type);`, and then you wrote`Mat ROI = checkMat( Rect(topLeft, bottomRight) );`. So one is taking different parameters than the other. Provide the implementation of `checkMat()` with your question

Comment: @KhalilKhalaf In this code, `checkMat` is a `cv::Mat` object, not a function. The first use is defining constructing the Mat; the second use is extracting a view.